# Reportviewer regular expression check

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reportviewer2008

In my report viewer i have a table displaying data in different columns. I wanted to have a regular expression to check the content in a textbox of a table to see if it is NULL to place a 0 in the textbox. Currently if there is returned data it is displayed and if not then there is empty space which i would like to replace it with a 0

here is what i had for a regular expression for the textbox:

=IIf(Fields!FirstAmount.Value = " ","0",Fields!FirstAmount.Value)

Any ideas or other ways to resolve this issue.

Comment: This is not a regular expression, this is just a if/then check on the textbox value.

Comment: Will then i meant an expression.... any feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my issue using the following expression:

=IIF(Fields!FirstAmount.Value Is Nothing, "0", Fields!FirstAmount.Value)

depending if the First Amount field is null or not it will be replaced by 0 if it is empty and if not it will show its data.